# Usage of public JSON service within JS Bin + OPEN UI5 app

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5, jsbin

I wanted to play around a little bit with OpenUI5 and JS Bin. And use a public JSON service for some mock data.

However I am not able to load data to my JSONModel from [this public JSON service](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts) within JS Bin.

Please check
[My Example](https://jsbin.com/dozede/1/edit?html,console,output) where I set the data manually and everything is working as expected. But after uncommenting this line (and of course commenting the next line):

```
oModel.loadData("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
```

I would expect that the JSON model loads data from that service and displays the data in the output table.

Unfortunately after loading data when I try to check the oModel variable in the console, for example like this:

```
oModel.getData()
```

I am expecting that getData() returns that JSON data, but I am getting an javascript object.
What am I  missing? Is it even possible to use an public JSON service within JS Bin?

Thanks

Comment: Open your JS console. Read the messages. *sap-ui-core.js:71 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://null.jsbin.com/runner' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.*

Comment: Thanks! I actually didn't check my browser console. Just the JS Bin console.

So if I understand it correctly - it is possible to use public JSON service in JS Bin, only if it is served over HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

The browser doesn´t allow mixed content.
If you have a website over https, you must include your model with https.

For testing purposes you can start your chrome with --disable-web-security.
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security`

Or you can use this chrome extension to allow it:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Answer (score 1):

CORS issue for you here...you can call the service like this "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/"

Please have a look at Nabi's tutorial: [tutorial](https://nabisoft.com/tutorials/sapui5/sapui5-single-file-template-using-xmlviews-controllers-fragments-and-custom-controls-for-bug-illustrations-support-requests-or-demos)